# Managed app installation on Salesforce Production Org

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, beta-managed-package, security-review, production

*Salesforce has two versions of Managed app*

1. Managed App ( **Beta** )
2. Managed App ( **Released** )

Currently inorder to do a prototype testing I released a Managed App (Beta) and simulated how a real installation would look like in Sandbox Org.

But while Upgrading the Managed App (Beta) in same Org I encountered an error saying "can't upgrade a Beta App".

Currently I released my Managed app and sent for Salesforce Security review process. I have some unknowns here. Please help me understanding the same.

1. Will I be able to install Managed Package ( Beta ) in a Production Org with installation URL ( even though upgrades are not possible )
2. Will I be able to install the Managed Package ( Released ) through unique package installation URL  ( without using AppExchange 'get it now' link ) without getting approval from Security review.
3. Will I be able push Patches to Customer who installed the packages through this URL.

or

only option to install Managed Package would be using Salesforce AppExchange  for Production org ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing beta package releases into production orgs is *not* possible except in very special cases (the "production" orgs created via the partner portal), so the answer to your first question is almost always no.

For your second question, you can bypass the appexchange if you want, and distribute your app directly via it's install link, certainly. If you don't go through security review some benefits of being a managed app are witheld however. For example, if you go through security review tabs in your app don't count against the customer's tab limit for their org, but if you skip the review they *do* count.

You can still use the license management app with a non-reviewed application by creating a private appexchange listing and using that to manage the license settings, however going through security review is recommended of course.

Push upgrades are only available to apps that have undergone security review, and once that's done have to be enabled by salesforce support for your dev org.

Comment: Thanks Peterson. That is really helpful. I sent my app (Released) using the installation Url and customer was able to install the same on their production Org.

Comment: If you plan to install it at more than 1 customer I'd really strongly recommend the security review, but if it's only for one or two customers there's no reason to bother with it.

Comment: Yeah I submitted the app for Security Review. But due to Dreamforce 2013 it seems there would be a significant delay in the process, for apps submitted post September 2013 [link](http://blogs.developerforce.com/isv/2013/07/get-ready-for-dreamforce-submit-your-app-for-security-review-by-september-8.html). For the time being I would go with installation URL approach, till it gets pushed to Appexchange. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

1. Yes, you can install manage package(Beta) to production org. But to install manage pacakge(Released) you first have to uninstall the Beta package from that org. It wont allow to install Managed package over Beta however, you can install another Beta package on it.

2.Yes, you can install Manage Package through unique package installation URL. Only thing is you have to logged in into customers org to install it and you cant track which org has installed it if you are creating it for business purpose i.e. you wont have control over license for your package used by customer(Customer can use app with no expiration date).

3.You can install patches by uploading it(Beta or Managed). This will create link(similar to new release) from that you can install it in customers org. Only thing is you wont be able to add new class to the patch..you can only modify components from the package.

Comment: The only "production" orgs you can install beta packages into are those created by the partner portal. Real customer production orgs cannot have beta packages installed.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as ca_peterson noted.